# no matching function for call to 'MY_OBJ::MY_OBJ()'

Tags: c++, object, oop

I'm trying to use `raylib` in `cpp` and compare it with `python` wrapper.

I created some classes and some of them takes arguments as type of other:

For example:

I have a class named `Point` which takes two `floats` as arguments.

I have a class named `Vector` which takes a `Point` as argument.

And I have a class named `Body` which takes some arguments as `float` and `Vector`s.

Basic scheme:

```
//INCLUDES ETC

class Point{
private:
    float x;
    float y;
    bool is_degree = true;

public:

    Point(float _x=0, float _y=0){
        set_x(_x);
        set_y(_y);
    }
// Methods (setters, getters etc)


};

class Vector{
private:
    Point p;
public:
    Vector(Point _p){
        set_p(_p);
    }
// Methods (setters, getters etc)

};



class Body{
private:
    float m;
    Vector pos;
    Vector vel;
    Vector acc;

    Body(float _m, Point _pos, Vector _vel,
         Vector _acc){

    }

};
```

The compiler complains:  `error: no matching function for call to 'Vector::Vector()'`

When I change the types of `pos`, `vel`, `acc` to something other then `Vector` it works.

I found when I pass a wrong type (object) to a method I get this error. But I did not pas anything. My `main.cpp` is doing nothing except including the `core.h`.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include "raylib.h"
#include "core.h"

int main(void)
{

}
```

Does anyone know what I'm missing here?

Comment: You defined a constructor for Vector requiring an argument, so now Base can't construct its member Vectors without an argument supplied. Put the Body constructor arguments in a member initializer list.

Comment: So initializing the `pos`, `vel` and `acc` in the `Body` will solve the problem?

Comment: `Vector pos;` -- The constructor you wrote for `Vector` requires an argument, thus the default constructor no longer exists.

Comment: Put simply, you haven't specified how to construct those three `Vector` objects and - as your error tells you - default construction is not an option.  `Vector` has no default constructor.

Comment: @MSH You created the `Vector` class, and explicitly wrote the code to say "when a Vector is constructed, it must be created with a `Point` argument".  That's exactly what your code is saying, but for some reason, you didn't realize it.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this simplification:

```
class Vector {
public:
    Vector(Point);
private:
    Point pt;
};

class Body {
public:
    Body(Point);
private:
    Vector pos;
};
```

Having defined a constructor for Vector requiring an argument, you cannot construct a Body unless an argument is provided to its Vector member. That is the meaning of the error `error: no matching function for call to 'Vector::Vector()`. The compiler tried to construct the Vectors in Body without arguments, but failed because no constructor without arguments was available. You can solve the problem with a member initializer list:

```
class Body {
public:
    Body(Point p) : pos(p) { }
private:
    Vector pos;
};
```

Comment: You see, since I never created an object from the class `Body` I was like: "I did not do anything yet. What is this?". But I think I need to think less Python-like. And by adding a default value to `Vector` which is a `Point` at `(0, 0)` I solve the problem. But your answer was enlightening. Thank you.